# Отладка cocos2d-x на Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, native

Не получается запустить отладку cocos2d-x на Android Studio 1.4 — требует использовать Gradle 2.5.  У кого-нибудь это вообще получилось?

На сайте: [Android Ndk Ppreview](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview) написано

> First, the Android NDK support only works with the new experimental Gradle plugin for Android (which in turn requires Gradle 2.5, released yesterday.)

Comment: Какая версия Android Studio и cocos2d-x?

Comment: Кроме того в моих проектах используются версии gradle от 2.4 до 2.7, не знаю с чего вы взяли что она `требует` 2.5

Comment: @anber: вам тут ответили.